# PHP - File upload not working

Tags: php, file-upload

When this code below runs, it just returns the `echo "Did not move files!";`
Goal is to allow users to upload files, just get this working for now.

account.php

```
<form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

upload.inc.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uploadsDir = '../uploads/';
$name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$tempName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
$error = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];

if ($error > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $error . "<br />";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploadsDir/$name");

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploadsDir/$name")) {

        echo "Successful";
        echo "Upload: " . $name . "<br />";
        echo "Stored in: Uploads Directory!";
    } else {
        echo "Did not move files!";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Hosting server off localhost, originally thought my directories did not have permissions to rwx, i ended up changing every directory that is used to have full permissions by any user. This did not change the outcome.

Comment: Because you already moved it in the previous line. You should run `move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploadsDir/$name")` only once.

Comment: if you are hosting off localhost, the you must specify the directory including the name of the external host

Comment: @HtmHell Did this and still returns same error message

Comment: Then now you should make sure the directory exists & is writeable.You can check that by using `var_dump(is_dir($uploadsDir) && is_writable($uploadsDir));`

Comment: @FredRawllings This was unsuccessful as well

Comment: @HtmHell It return true, will test this for tmp folder aswell just incase but for readable

Comment: @James check your temp_name variable it has not been defined

Comment: @James The name of your variable is tempName not temp_name

Comment: You have another 2 errors: [1] You declared `$tempName`, but you are using `$temp_name` [2] you are using `basename` for the temp variable

Comment: @FredRawllings Both of you guys, this worked, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @HtmHell Both of you guys, this worked, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @James you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 3 errors:

1. You called `move_uploaded_file` twice.
2. You declared `$tempName` variable, but you used `$temp_name` in the `move_uploaded_file` function.
3. You used `basename` when declaring the temporary file path variable.

Your final code should look like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uploadsDir = '../uploads/';
    $name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $tempName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];

    if ($error > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $error . "<br />";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempName, "$uploadsDir/$name")) {

            echo "Successful";
            echo "Upload: " . $name . "<br />";
            echo "Stored in: Uploads Directory!";
        } else {
            echo "Did not move files!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uploadsDir = '/';
$name = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$tempName = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
$error = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];

if ($error > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $error . "<br />";
} else {

    if(move_uploaded_file($tempName, __DIR__.'/'.$name)) {

        echo "Successful";
        echo "Upload: " . $name . "<br />";
        echo "Stored in: Uploads Directory!";
    } else {
        echo "Did not move files!";
    }
}
}
```